# How to obtain a star product of a pair of functionals in matter sector?

Tags: string-theory, deformation-quantization

In lecture notes *D-branes, Tachyons and String field theory* by Washington Taylor and Barton Zwiebach in the topic "Witten's cubic bosonic SFT" there they define a star product and when star product acting on a pair of functionals $\phi$ and $\psi$ it gets factorized into separate matter and ghost parts. In the matter sector how can we calculate the star product of the two functionals?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I am calculating the star product of two string fields \psi and \phi . As mentioned above that star product of these two fields gets factorized into two seperate sectors one is matter sector and the other is ghost sector. So how can I  calculate the star product in one of any sector.

Comment: Link to abstract page?